# Chrome extension stops working after a while. Response is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this strange bug with a chrome extension, that is supposed to communicate between content script and background page. It seems to work for a while, but suddenly it stops working. The only way to get it to work again is to uninstall the extension and reinstall it. This happens to both the version on the chrome store, and my local developer version. (Reloading the developer version does **not** fix the issue.)

The relevant part is:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        //response is undefined at this point
    });
});
```

I see from inspecting the page that the content script is indeed injected into the relevant page, but the code inside the listener never run:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  //never runs this code
});
```

You can find the installed version here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hi-res-cover-art-grabber/oiagpaldkopdbolnebgjlmihmejjkaji
And the full sourcecode here: 
https://github.com/MrMamen/CoverGrabber/tree/master/chrome

Comment: Does reloading the _page_ that the content script is injected into help? How often does this happen? Without looking at the source code - how is the content script injected?

Comment: Reloading does not help. But I do need to reload after uninstalling/installing.  I just realized it seems to break every time I close my browser. The error is probably in the initialization? https://github.com/MrMamen/CoverGrabber/blob/master/chrome/background.js

Comment: Similar issue here, after a while (few days/weeks) - by chrome extension background script completely disappears (when I open the debugger tools on the background page). Extremely weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your JavaScript in your `background.js` is in a `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` event which only gets called on install and on updates, so it isn't called when you reopen your browser.

You'll want to make sure to register your events outside of this or else your extension will only register the events when you uninstall and reinstall your extension as you mentioned.